# Python: PDF to text is consuming too much CPU

Tags: python, flask, pdf

I'm trying to convert a large pdf to text. The file is about 20 MB. No matter what python library I use, the CPU spikes to 99% or more. I have an app deployed on AWS with 1 vcpu / 8GB RAM and the server hangs when I try to extract text from more than one file in parallel. Backend is a flask app.

I've tried unstructuredio, pdfminer, pypdf2, pymupdf and a few more.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Using parallel executions **_always_** consumes more CPU time than executions one by one, because of the logic required for handling the parallelism itself. Can be 30% additional CPU consumption. Also, the closer you get to 100% CPU utilization, the worse is that overhead: the machine is under stress. So you must bargain execution time vs. CPU load and serialize executions. Using pure Python packages obviously also adds to CPU consumption because of their in-built inefficiencies.

Comment: I tested this on my local machine (mac os). Even with one file, the CPU hits 99%